# Load image like instagram

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

1. if my image is downloaded 15% then it shows full image but with
   unclear pixel.
2. if image is downloaded 50% then also it shows full image but with 
   improved clarity of the picture or photo.

so after 100% download the image should be clear cut in view.

So does anyone have idea about how to do this in android.

Comment: use can use any image downloading library that has "lazyloading".

Comment: @AshwaniKumar i am not ask about lazy loading. but if you see in instagram application, how they are loading images in imageview. i want that feature.

Comment: use multiple images quality ... like thumb, low, and normal quality ... load thumb first ... so it can be shown as noraml quality image is loading ... or use "interlaced" images ..

Comment: @Selvin for that i have to load 3 images(thumb, low,normal) at a time from different url?

Comment: @Selvin i think "interlaced" images may be helpful. thanks.

Comment: Yes, afaik SKIA(image library used in android) and Drawable/Bitmap classes from Android API are not supporting interleced png nor progressvie jpg ... so it would be hard to write own Drawable class with would be support it (you will need to find library first) edit: maybe fresco does it ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817124/blur-thumbnail-image-before-loading-actual-image-in-picasso/49855514#49855514

Comment: @Prashant finally how you did this.?

Answer (score 4):

First load a low quality copy of your image then scale it and apply blur effect on it. Display this image until your high resolution picture is downloading. Facebook wrote a [blog post](https://code.facebook.com/posts/991252547593574/the-technology-behind-preview-photos/) about it and I think they use the same technique.

Comment: Instagram API provides 3 sizes, thumbnail, low_resolution and standard_resolution URLs, load thumbnail and then standard_resolution, I have done the same in web app not android, it works : https://www.picodash.com

Answer (score 2):

Use Picasso library to load images in your project. 
Link - http://square.github.io/picasso/

The thing that you want to do can be done by creating a **BASE64** version of your image and then use it as a **placeholder** while loading an image with picasso.

Example code -

```
picasso.load(finalImage)
       .placeholder(Base64Image)
       .into(imageHolder)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how to do this with Glide ?

Comment: @Woods I haven't used it so can't really help you with this. I prefer picasso and have been using it for a few months now.

Comment: No problem, Good day annsh !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Glide or Fresco Library . Following steps demonstrate how to do this using Glide Library

**Step 1:** you need 2 images . first image is the original image and second image is the thumbnail image of max 30x30 dimension and 2,3kb size

**Step2:** use following code to load the Thumbnail image using Glide and blurr the thumbnail

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = findViewById(R.id.image);



    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load("thumbnailURL")
            .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.d("imageblurness", "onResourceReady: Image Failed");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
           Bitmap blurr = fastblur(resource,0.3f,2);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blurr);

            GlideApp.with(MainActivity.this).load("OriginalImageUrl")
                  .placeholder(d)
                  .into(image);

           return true;
        }
    }).submit();


}

public Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap, float scale, int radius) {

    int width = Math.round(sentBitmap.getWidth() * scale);
    int height = Math.round(sentBitmap.getHeight() * scale);
    sentBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sentBitmap, width, height, false);

    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

    if (radius < 1) {
        return (null);
    }

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    int[] pix = new int[w * h];
    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    int wm = w - 1;
    int hm = h - 1;
    int wh = w * h;
    int div = radius + radius + 1;

    int r[] = new int[wh];
    int g[] = new int[wh];
    int b[] = new int[wh];
    int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
    int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

    int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
    divsum *= divsum;
    int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
    for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
        dv[i] = (i / divsum);
    }

    yw = yi = 0;

    int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
    int stackpointer;
    int stackstart;
    int[] sir;
    int rbs;
    int r1 = radius + 1;
    int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
    int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
            sir = stack[i + radius];
            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
            rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
            gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
            bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }
        }
        stackpointer = radius;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

            r[yi] = dv[rsum];
            g[yi] = dv[gsum];
            b[yi] = dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (y == 0) {
                vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
            }
            p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

            sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
            sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi++;
        }
        yw += w;
    }
    for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
        yp = -radius * w;
        for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
            yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

            sir = stack[i + radius];

            sir[0] = r[yi];
            sir[1] = g[yi];
            sir[2] = b[yi];

            rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

            rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
            gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
            bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

            if (i > 0) {
                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];
            } else {
                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];
            }

            if (i < hm) {
                yp += w;
            }
        }
        yi = x;
        stackpointer = radius;
        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
            pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

            rsum -= routsum;
            gsum -= goutsum;
            bsum -= boutsum;

            stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
            sir = stack[stackstart % div];

            routsum -= sir[0];
            goutsum -= sir[1];
            boutsum -= sir[2];

            if (x == 0) {
                vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
            }
            p = x + vmin[y];

            sir[0] = r[p];
            sir[1] = g[p];
            sir[2] = b[p];

            rinsum += sir[0];
            ginsum += sir[1];
            binsum += sir[2];

            rsum += rinsum;
            gsum += ginsum;
            bsum += binsum;

            stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
            sir = stack[stackpointer];

            routsum += sir[0];
            goutsum += sir[1];
            boutsum += sir[2];

            rinsum -= sir[0];
            ginsum -= sir[1];
            binsum -= sir[2];

            yi += w;
        }
    }

    Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
    bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    return (bitmap);
}
```

in OnResoursceReady Function we load the original image and use the blurr thumbnail image as placeholder