# Blur thumbnail image before loading actual image in picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

i am using picasso to display the image from URL, i am displaying thumbnail image first before loading actual image, i want to blur that thumbnail image , how i can achieve in picasso ?

here is my source code

```
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(thumbUrl) // thumbnail url goes here
                //.placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .resize(width, width)
                .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 25, 1))
                .into(imageview, new Callback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG,"OnSuccess");
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(url) // image url goes here
                                .resize(width, width)
                                .placeholder(imageview.getDrawable())
                                .into(imageview);
                        iv_reDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG,"OnError");
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(url) // image url goes here
                                .resize(width, width)
                                .placeholder(imageview.getDrawable())
                                .into(imageview);
                        iv_reDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i solved my problem with the help of this [Library](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) named as picasso-transformations , i added the below dependencies in my project

```
compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
```

not only it support **Picasso** but also it support  **Glide** or **Fresco** too
and i called the `BlurTransformation` class inside picasso.

here is complete example

```
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(thumbUrl) // thumbnail url goes here
                //.placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .resize(width, width)
                .transform(new BlurTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 25, 1))
                .into(imageview, new Callback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG,"OnSuccess");
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(url) // image url goes here
                                .resize(width, width)
                                .placeholder(imageview.getDrawable())
                                .into(imageview);
                        iv_reDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.e(TAG,"OnError");
                        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(url) // image url goes here
                                .resize(width, width)
                                .placeholder(imageview.getDrawable())
                                .into(imageview);
                        iv_reDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge Picasso currently doesn't support this "feature". Glide library, which has very similar usage, does have a function that enables easy usage of "fast preview", that is low resolution thumbnail which is loaded faster than full size image.

Function is `thumbnail(float)` and accepts scale factor as argument, where for example `0.1f` is one-tenth of original image size.

Case usage with Glide could be something like this.

```
Glide.with(mFragment)
            .load(wFile.getUriForThumb())                
            .override(length, length)
            .thumbnail(.05f)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image_128px)
            .into(holder.mImageThumb);
```

Where method `override` is an close equivalent to `resize(int,int)` in Picasso.

For complete comparison between two libraries you can check this nice guide: [Glide vs. Picasso](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d)

Answer (score 1):

## Blur Transformation in Picasso, Reference: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-rotation-and-transformation

```
 @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
            // Create another bitmap that will hold the results of the filter.
            Bitmap blurredBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
        Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
        Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());

        // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        script.setInput(input);

        // Set the blur radius
        script.setRadius(10);

        // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
        script.forEach(output);

        // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
        output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return blurredBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested both Glide and Picasso for fast loading if you resize your image in Picasso the it will improve your loading speed, here is the code

```
 Glide.with(context)
           .load(sArr.get(position).getThumbnail())
           .thumbnail(0.01f)
           .override(100,100)
           .centerCrop()
           .placeholder(R.drawable.default_picture)
           .into(holder.imgItem);
```

Code for Piccaso

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(sArr.get(position).getThumbnail())
            .resize(100,100)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.default_picture)
            .into(holder.imgItem);
```

> **and Picasso win !!**

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work but I have seen before that you can use:

```
.add(new ImageTransform(IMAGE_URL, new BlurTransformation(this)));
```

Comment: is this `add` function available in Picasso ?